# Different behavior with different types of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

i  have tested two different   varianat of similary code ,suppose i have   char array

```
char x[]="snow comes in winter ";
```

then following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

char x[]="snow comes in winter ";
int k=0;
int n=3;
cout<<x+n-k+1<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

prints `"comes in winter "` 
while following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

//char x[]="snow comes in winter ";
int a[]={12,3,2,4,5,6,7};
int k=0;
int n=3;
cout<<a+n-k+1<<endl;



return 0;
}
```

prints `0xbffd293c` 
if we change it a bit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

//char x[]="snow comes in winter ";
int a[]={12,3,2,4,5,6,7};
int k=0;
int n=3;
cout<<*(a+n-k+1)<<endl;



return 0;
}
```

prints number 5.
so my question is why we can access   in case of char array so easily?what is main reason of it?i am very curiousy and please could anybody explain me?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: ok  why does it show me different  result for different type of array?(in this case char  and integer array are given)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why we can access in case of char array so easily?

Because there's a convention that C strings are represented by `char*`, people assume `char*` are actually strings. The `iostream`s follow that and overload output for `char*` to print the string, whereas for an `int*` (in your second example), they print the representation of the address.

BTW there is a similar overload for input, which is most unfortunate, since you can't control that to prevent buffer overflows. ie. don't do this:

```
char x[10];
std::cin >> x;
```

Comment: You can look this up in `iostream` (or, more correctly, in `ostream`) for whichever C++ standard library you're using, and verify that this is true for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons for this go back to C.

In C, `char*` is typically used to represent a NUL-terminated string (as opposed to a pointer to an individual `char`). Therefore, functions taking `char*` typically treat the argument as a string. In this case the function is `operator<<`, and what it does is print the argument out as a string.

No such thing can be said about `int*`, which is just that, a pointer to an `int`. Here, `operator<<` prints out the value of the pointer (i.e. the address). It's only when you explicitly dereference the pointer that the pointed-to value gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

The left shift operator for cout is overloaded to handle char pointers.  Meaning, when you give it a pointer to a char, it dereferences the pointer for you and so you get the data pointed to.  This does not happen in the case of an int because there is no overload, and so you must dereference the pointer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Given a variable `foo` of type `Foo*`, the expression `foo+n` is also of type `Foo*` (assuming `n` is an integral type).

The default `std::ostream` mechanism for printing a pointer is to print the pointer. There is an override specifically for `const char*` pointers, which is to print the (presumably) null terminated string pointed to by that pointer.

Bottom line: Pointers that are not `char*` will be printed as pointers. Pointers that are `char*` will be printed as a string.